# How to know the Objective-C language version in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to check the Objective-C version that I am using in my App

Comment: Did you mean OS version? You can check system version using these `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`

Comment: Why you want in Xcode? What to do with that?

Comment: Check the Objective-C compiler you are using in your Build Settings

Comment: Does the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/) help?

Comment: see this for help: [Runtime Versions and Platforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html)

Answer (score 6):

The Objective-C level of language support is defined by the version of Clang used to compile the code, which is itself very close to the version of Xcode.

```c
#if __clang_major__ >= 11
    NSLog(@"My Objective-C language support is what Apple Clang/Xcode 11.x can support.");
    // This language version supports the additional features/fixes written under "Apple Clang Compiler"
    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes
    // Notably this version adds Objective-C support to:
    // - `[[clang::no_destroy]]` and `[[clang::always_destroy]]`

#elif __clang_major__ >= 10
    NSLog(@"My Objective-C language support is what Apple Clang/Xcode 10.x can support.");
    // This language version supports the additional features/fixes written under "Apple Clang Compiler"
    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes
    // Notably this version adds macro support to:
    // - detect most builtin pseudo-functions with `__has_builtin`

#elif __clang_major__ >= 9
    NSLog(@"My Objective-C language support is what Apple Clang/Xcode 9.x can support.");
    // This language version supports the additional features/fixes written under "Apple LLVM Compiler and Low-Level Tools"
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW878
    // Notably this version adds Objective-C support for:
    // - the `@available` language feature

#elif __clang_major__ >= 8
    NSLog(@"My Objective-C language support is what Apple Clang/Xcode 8.x can support.");
    // This language version supports the additional features/fixes written under "Objective-C and C++"
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW78
    // Notably this version adds Objective-C support for:
    // - the `@property (class)` language feature

#elif __clang_major__ >= 7
    NSLog(@"My Objective-C language support is what Apple Clang/Xcode 7.x can support.");
    // This language version supports the additional features/fixes written under "Objective-C"
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW326
    // Notably this version adds Objective-C support for:
    // - `CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED` and `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED`
    // - `__kindof`
    // - `_Nullable`, `_Nonnull`, and `_Null_unspecified`
    // - Lightweight generics like `NSArray<UIImage *> *` and `NSDictionary<NSString *, NSURL *>`

#elif __clang_major__ >= 6
    NSLog(@"My Objective-C language support is what Apple Clang/Xcode 6.x can support.");
    // This language version supports the additional features/fixes written at:
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW453

#else
    NSLog(@"My Objective-C language support is so old that I won't even be allowed to publish this on any App Store nowadays.");

#endif
```

You may also use `__clang_minor__` if you need more precision for the version being used.

Whenever possible, it is advised to use [`__has_builtin`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#feature-checking-macros) to check the availability of Objective-C language features instead of `__clang_major__` and `__clang_minor__`.

Some notable other older historical language features that you shouldn't even bother testing for availability anymore:

- `NS_ENUM` and `NS_OPTIONS` were added in Xcode 4.5
- `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` subscripting were added in Xcode 4.4 / 4.5
- `@YES` and `@NO` literals were added in Xcode 4.4 / 4.5
- `NSNumber`, `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` literals were added in Xcode 4.4
- `@autoreleasepool` blocks were added in Xcode 4.2
- "*Objective-C 2.0*" is something VERY old (Xcode 2.x)

Lastly "*Modern Objective-C*" just refers to any currently available Xcode support for Objective-C.

Related:

- [How can I reliably detect the version of clang at preprocessing time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19387043/1033581)

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of the Objective-C runtime—“modern” and “legacy”. iPhone applications and 64-bit programs on OS X v10.5 and later use the modern version of the runtime.check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html)

All major features introduced in objective-c, You can check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/)