# How can I translate the following code snippet from Swift to Objective-C?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, compilation, macros

How can I translate the following code snippet from Swift to Objective-C?

```
#if compiler(>=5.5)
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    myTableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0
}
#endif
```

Alternatively, is there any macro in objective c side that assists to know the compiler version?

---

[Cy-4AH suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70737560/how-to-translate-the-following-code-snippet-from-swift-to-objective-c#comment125052485_70737560) and answer that used,

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_13_0
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    ...
}
#endif
```

However, in my case `#ifdef __IPHONE_15_0` is not available in Xcode 12.x.

Comment: Of course condition compiler >= 5.5 is not valid for objective-c. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I want to build the code for ios15 in xcode12.4 by restricting compilation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58083853/1934750

Comment: @Cy-4AH it didnt help. Please see the updated post.

Comment: That is very odd that it's now available in Xcode 12.x

Comment: @Cy-4AH yes, thus that does not help of achieving what I need.

Comment: Yes they should be missing, `_IPHONE_15_0_` appeared in Xcode 13.0

Comment: You need somehow put iOS 15 SDK inside Xcode 12. The easiest way to do it is to update to 13 :)

Comment: @Cy-4AH My MacBook Pro, mid 2012 does not support latest macOS to support xcode13. I need this workaround.

Comment: Try to check the clang version : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608546/how-to-know-the-objective-c-language-version-in-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem with a workaround discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58010808/1084174).

```
#if __clang_major__ >= 12
    NSLog(@"My Objective-C language support is what Apple Clang/Xcode 12.x can support.");
#endif
```

**Note** that the **clang_major**, **clang_minor**, etc. variables resemble (are almost the same as) the Xcode versions and need careful investigation before usage.